# How to transfer from iPhone album to Mac

Tags: iphone, album

My iPhone contains pictures from camera roll and pictures I synced from my previous Mac to the iPhone album. The hard drive broke on my Mac and I couldn't recover the images stored on the iPhone albumns. On iTunes or iPhoto I can only recover pictures from Camera roll but not the albums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 3rd party software like [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/).

Answer (score 0):

Connect the iPhone to MAC using USB cable and then Use the `ImageCapture.app` in MAC to copy all the Photo and Video files from iPhone to MAC